# split does not return empty elements

Tags: perl

Why do these not all return bbb?

```
$ perl -e '$a="  "; print map { "b" } split / /, $a;'
<<nothing>>
$ perl -e '$a=",,"; print map { "b" } split /,/, $a;'
<<nothing>>
$ perl -e '$a="  a"; print map { "b" } split / /, $a;'
bbb
$ perl -e '$a=",,a"; print map { "b" } split /,/, $a;'
bbb
```

I would have expected `split` to return an array with 3 elements in all cases.

```
$ perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 24 subversion 1) configuration:
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`split`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/split)'s third parameter says how many elements to produce:

> #### `split /PATTERN/,EXPR,LIMIT`
>
> ...
>   If `LIMIT` is negative, it is treated as if it were instead arbitrarily large; as many fields as possible are produced.
>
> If `LIMIT` is omitted (or, equivalently, zero), then it is usually treated as if it were instead negative but with the exception that trailing empty fields are stripped (empty leading fields are always preserved); if all fields are empty, then all fields are considered to be trailing (and are thus stripped in this case).

It defaults to `0`, which means as many as possible *but leaving off any trailing empty elements*.

You can pass `-1` as the third argument to `split` to suppress this behavior.

Comment: Wow thanks, did not not know `split` could take a third argument